# Embed two online websites in one HTML page

Tags: html

I am trying to embed two websites in one page like YouTube and Google using div tags and the links in between the div tags....is there any way this could work?

Comment: You would need two iframes, and just put them in your div container.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the [`<iframe>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) tag.

Comment: Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

> Their is three types which I define to add any other website in your webpage.
>
> **Note: But nowadays Google, Facebook, and other lots of websites do not allow you to load their website or webpage on your Webpage for some security issues.**

```html
<iframe src="https://www.example.com" height="200" width="300"></iframe>

<object data="https://www.example.com" width="400" height="300" type="text/html">
    Alternative Content
</object>

<embed src="https://www.example.com" width=200 height=200 onerror="alert('URL invalid !!');" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Iframes with the links set to your desired pages

Answer (score 0):

Generally the iframe-tag is used to embed whole websites. (see [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)) But appearantly youtube & google have blocked that option. (see when running the snippet below)

```html
<iframe
    width="500"
    height="100"
    src="https://www.wikipedia.org">
</iframe>

<iframe
    width="500"
    height="100"
    src="https://www.google.com">
</iframe>

<iframe
    width="500"
    height="100"
    src="https://www.youtube.com">
</iframe>
```